# request a resource with json format - curl:(7) couldn't connect to host

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to learn from a tutorial how to use Rails as Backend for an iPhone Application. And it seems I fail at a very early beginning. 
The tutorial says after I created the scaffold "Goal", I should add JSON handling to the respond_to blocks in the actions of the GoalsController:

```
def index
  @goals = Goal.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xml  { render :xml => @goals }
    format.json { render :json => @goals }
  end
end
```

by the way, that's how my scaffolded controller was filled before:

```
  def index
    @goals = Goal.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @goals }
    end
  end
```

the error happens when I want to request resource with a json format (yes, I already filled the table with data):

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000/goals/1.json
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

My questions: 
1. Is this step necessary for me if there's already some json-code (even with different syntax)? 
2. how to solve the problem? I just followed the instructions and nothing more...

some additional note: The tutorial deals with Rails 3.0 and I have Rails 3.2 on my machine. Are there some syntax-differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you start your rails server yet by running `rails s`? It seems you haven't started your rails server yet. After running this command, you should be able to see the incoming requests in your terminal.

The other thing is that your code is about `index` action, while you made request to the `show` action.

```
index
http://localhost:3000/goals.json

show
http://localhost:3000/goals/1.json
```

Comment: so I have to run my rails server while/before requesting the resource?
My steps were: 1. creating goal-scaffold 2. rake db:migrate 3. filling some data via browser 3. shut down server 4. editing the goals_controller 5. trying to request it. 
Yes, I also put the same JSON handling into the "show" action and to any other possible actions- but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, you need to start your rails server whenever you request the resource, otherwise there is nothing to handle your requests. When you start rails server, it starts listening on port 3000 and waiting for incoming requests and respond it back.

Comment: I got it! I was on the wrong road. Thought I have to access `$ curl http://localhost:3000/goals/1.json` via terminal. When I type it in my browser address bar, it works fine after starting server. Thanks alot. Just had a wrong understanding what's going on there.